# css 100vh scroll stops after 3rd section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to scroll by every section, it's working but it won't scroll to the last section just stops at the 3rd one and won't move down after that.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    <div class="body" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
      <section id="red" class="bc1">
      </section>
      <section id="blue" class="bc2">
      </section>
      <section id="green" class="bc3">
      </section>
      <section id="blue" class="bc4">
      </section>
    </div>



     <script>

    var $pages = $('section'), tot = $pages.length, c = 0, pagePos = 0, down = 0, listen = true;
    $('.body').on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!listen)
            return;
        listen = false;
        down = e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0;
        c = Math.min(Math.max(0, down ? ++c : --c), tot - 1);
        pagePos = $pages.eq(c).offset().top;

        $(this).stop().animate({
            scrollTop : pagePos
        }, 850, function() {
            listen = true;
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Change the fourth section id to another color. Ids are unique, assign an id to only one element per page. So ex. `<section id="yellow" class="bc4">
      </section>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that offset measures the distance of the element from the top of the body. But once you have scrolled the offset is different since the elements have moved closer/further from the last scroll.

So in order to account for this you need to add the `scrollTop()` of the `.body` element.

Updated code

```js
var $pages = $('section'),
  tot = $pages.length,
  c = 0,
  pagePos = 0,
  down = 0,
  listen = true,
  body = $('.body');
body.on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!listen)
    return;
  listen = false;
  down = e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0;
  c = Math.min(Math.max(0, down ? ++c : --c), tot - 1);
  pagePos = $pages.eq(c).offset().top + body.scrollTop();

  $(this).stop().animate({
    scrollTop: pagePos
  }, 850, function() {
    listen = true;
  });

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.bc1,
.bc2,
.bc3,
.bc4 {
  height: 100vh;
}

#red {
  background: red;
}

#blue {
  background: blue;
}

#green {
  background: green;
}

.body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
  <section id="red" class="bc1"></section>
  <section id="blue" class="bc2"></section>
  <section id="green" class="bc3"></section>
  <section id="blue" class="bc4"></section>
</div>
```